# React-app Google OAuth2 .0 Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

[image: Google OAuth2 Error 400]

I have initially set Authorized URI in Google Developer Console as "http://localhost:3000/" but it gives error as above.

I tried by replacing it with "http://localhost:3000/login/google/return" as error image, but by doing it instead of logging in successfully it redirects to same login page again.

Plz help me.

Comment: Please clarify what's the question here, if possible include more details (what have you tried, what documentation you refered etc).

Answer (score 0):

Go to google cloud platform next to your  OAuth 2.0 client and add http://localhost into JS source